# how to set "Http11NioProtocol" in tomcat 7.0.37?

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7

I'm having trouble configuring tomcat to use "Http11NioProtocol".
the server.conf has the following settings:

```
<Connector
    protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
    port="80"
    redirectPort="8443"
    connectionTimeout="20000"
    compression="on" />
```

When we started the tomcat and open the application we see that the images are changed, for example in the image of items appearing in the picture sales and so on. The CSS is fine but the content of the images is wrong.
If we close the browser and reopen the images load fine. Also tried with other browsers and the same thing happens.

Does that make any other configuration in tomcat?